# Can one publish a paper that does not discover any new theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, article-writing

I'm an undergraduate student. I wonder if I discover a natural and intuitive way to introduce the materials in complex numbers and complex analysis that have not appeared in the textbooks, such like give another reasonable motivatation that why we define $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ like that, and  why do we must have define $\displaystyle\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ as sine function of $z$. I don't discover any new theorem, but to introduce these materials in a whole new manner. Can I publish a little paper?

Comment: How do you explain the complex numbers more naturally than $a+b\sqrt{-1}$? Is this really a novel idea? If not, you'll probably have trouble publishing it.

Comment: There are journals specifically about mathematics education, which might be interested.

Comment: You can certainly publish a new proof of a well known and important theorem in a good journal. In this case your new proof should be a substantial simplification, or derived in a new and revealing way.